# Modifying the representation of for loop in C

Tags: c, linux, representation

I have a the given for loop written multiple times and it is annoying to type that everytime.

Note that they are in they are in different functions.so, `code optimization isn't` the problem here. but instead `representation`

```
for(int j=0; j<PS; j++){
   for (int k=0; k<CLS;k++){
```

Would it be possible to represent it with the help of a `pragma` or something..
so, that I can use it in the following fashion..

```
#pragma mycurrentlooping
{
  blah[j][k]...
}
```

Would this be possible? if yes, how? or what is the best possible way to do this.

Would doing this effect the performance?

This may sound stupid..but i really have many such individual functions that do different operations.

Comment: -1: I think it is bad idea. If a partner has to read your code, it would be very "annoying" for him, because (s)he had to descipher your exotic syntax every time. The standard syntax of C for loops is well understood by every programmer. People not only write programs, but read them, also, and extrange code means a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#define` to define a MACRO for that, like this:

`#define loop_till(x)  for(int j=0; j<(x); j++)`

You do it at the top of your source file, then use it as:

```
loop_till(PS)
{
     loop_till(CLS)
     {
      ...
     }
}
```

To read more about (function like) pre-processor macros, read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros)

Comment: Add a parameter for the counter name and it's solved.

Comment: But can it be a two level for loop? Can you show me an example?

Comment: I don't like this approach. The index variables j, k, are used in the block tied to the for(;;) loop, but their declaration is hidden to the programmer by the macro. So, the answer is correct, but I think that is prefirable to write the "annoying" code every time, since is even more annoying to have exotic C code over there.

Comment: When would you use it, Pablo1977?

Comment: @pablo1977 :You are right, in that case we can pass `i` or `j` as parameter to macro. But since `i` and `j` are lvalues, I do not like that approach either.

Comment: @user3808088: What do you mean?

Comment: @user3808088: Ok, anyway, it seems you have not practice with macros. So, it is a good idea that you learn about that. I like macros a lot, they are really fun, but I avoid to use them most of the time. Macros are very good to define constants, and I use them a lot in debugging stage.

Comment: I use macros extensively. did not know how to use them for `for loops` and if they were any good. :)

Answer (score 1):

@Don'tYouWorryChild gives you the correct answer,

> But can it be a two level for loop? Can you show me an example?

If you want a one line macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOOP_outer(var, val) for (var = 0; var < val; var++)
#define LOOP_inner LOOP_outer
#define LOOP(outer, inner) LOOP_##outer LOOP_##inner

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;

    LOOP(outer(i, 5), inner(j, 10)) {
        printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expands to:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
 }
```

But is bad code (as there is no way to `break` or `continue` from the first loop)

Comment: The "from"-"to" thing is probably wrong, because the real meaning is actually "outer"-"inner".

Comment: Looks overcomplicated; what's wrong with: `#define LOOP(var, val) for (var = 0; var < val; var++)` followed by `LOOP(i, 5) LOOP(j, 10) { ... }`?

Comment: @Ruud, you are right, and as I say is bad code, but seems that OP wants to call the macro only once.

Comment: @AlterMann My guess is, OP just wants something short and simple. Oh, and your solution is not necessarily bad code; some reserve is appropriate (risk of obfuscation), but not for the reasons you gave. Too often, `break` and `continue` themselves are a sign of code smell. Oops sorry, didn't mean to start a flame war...